# how to remove commas from list of string values and get unique values from list

Tags: collections

I have a list of string values. I want to remove the duplicates from it.

```
List<String> numbers = form.getValues();
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
hs.addAll(numbers );
numbers .clear();
numbers .addAll(hs);

//number values will be -> 12342,12342, 23434,23434
```

I am unable to get the unique values even after converting into set because it has comma separated values.

Answer (score 1):

It would by great to know what do you get in the first line in your code. Do you have a one string with values and comma or few strings in number List.
In first case you have to split this long string. Otherwise you work only with one element list ...
just replace the first line with:

```
List<String> numbers = form.getValues().split(",");
```

Comment: number values will be -> 12342,12342, 23434,23434

Comment: form.getValues() gives the list of string values - 12342,12342, 23434,23434 .. I cannot use the function split(",") for list of string values

Comment: I tested it, and it works fine. I added some values manually. Result contains only unique values. Try it:         List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        numbers.add("11111");
        numbers.add("11111");
        numbers.add("11111");
        numbers.add("22222");

        Set<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
        hs.addAll(numbers );
        numbers .clear();
        numbers .addAll(hs);
        System.out.print(hs);      produces [22222, 11111]